# jQuery: insert a character first, THEN call the function

Tags: jquery

```
$("#textarea").keydown(function() {
    alert($("#textarea").val());
});
```

If user pressed a key, lets say "Z" button, and the current value of textarea is "something", it will show an alert message with "something", then adds the "Z" to the textarea.

What I want is to add the "Z" FIRST, then print "somethingZ", how to do that? should I use something different than keydown()? I don't want to use change() because I want to validate after each button key

Comment: Out-of-topic, but you could also change $("#textarea").val() to $(this).val(). If the id of the text area changes then there isn't so much renaming

Comment: @Tx3, not only that, it's more efficient too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value *after* the keypress, use the [`keyup` event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead of [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) (which hasn't changed the value yet), like this:

```
$("#textarea").keyup(function() {
  alert($("#textarea").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textarea").keyup(function () {
    alert($("#textarea").val());
});
```

Comment: +1 Post time indicates the poster probably didn't see Nick's answer before posting, so it does not deserve a down vote.